# How to visualize a list of coordinates in [x.y] format?

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I have a JSON file with coordinates representing roads stored in a list of lists. The coordinates are stored as [longitude, latitude] in a key called `path`. Example:

```
[[14.322689, 51.178513],
 [14.322731, 51.178459],
 [14.322689, 51.178349],
 [14.322562, 51.178304],
 [14.32253, 51.178259]]
```

What I want to achieve it to add these linestrings onto a Folium map. This code below works albeit it has the line in the 'wrong' location since it plotted it [lon, lat] instead of [lat, lon].

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[0,0], zoom_start=4)

chunks = pd.read_json(r'input_file.json', lines=True, chunksize = 20)

for chunk in chunks:
     chunk['geometry']= chunk['path'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
     gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(chunk, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry='geometry')

     for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    
          line = row['xxxx']
          folium.PolyLine(line, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(m)
```

What is the best way to handle efficiently flipping/transforming the coordinates on a large sample of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`folium.GeoJson`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.GeoJson). Example

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely import LineString

chunks = [
    {
        "path":[
            [14.322689, 51.178513],
            [14.322731, 51.178459],
            [14.322689, 51.178349],
            [14.322562, 51.178304],
            [14.32253, 51.178259]
        ]
    },
]

m = folium.Map(location=[51.178,14.323], zoom_start=18)

chunks = pd.DataFrame(chunks)
chunks['geometry'] = chunks['path'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(chunks, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry='geometry')

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    geo_j = gdf.geometry.to_json()
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j, style_function=lambda x: dict(color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1))
    geo_j.add_to(m)

m.show_in_browser()
```

[image]